# How to make some methods depends on another method before run in hangfire?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have this api endpoint method which uses `Hangfire`. How do I make sure that `PreIngestion()` is completed first before `IngestA()` and `IngestB()` could be executed?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("IngestFiles")]
public IActionResult IngestFiles(string cronExpression = "0")
{
     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>(x => x.PreIngestion(), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>(x => x.IngestA(), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>(x => x.IngestB(), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

     return Ok();
}
```

I can do it with ContinueJobWith method but I need it to be scheduled.

Comment: Create a helper method that calls each endpoint but waits for the result of the previous before calling the next one and schedule this method through Hangfire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `QueueAttribute` is not working for the recurring job,
you can create a helper method to queue them up as Anton said.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("IngestFiles")]
public IActionResult IngestFiles(string cronExpression = "0")
{
     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>(x => IngestHelper.Ingest(x), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

     return Ok();
}
```

RecurringJobHelper.cs

```
public static class RecurringJobHelper
{
    public static void Ingest(IIngestService ingestService)
    {
        ingestService.PreIngestion();
        ingestService.IngestA();
        ingestService.IngestB();
    }
}
```